# SQL Server query Using Bit column in Row_Number Order By

Tags: sql-server

I have this SQL Server query that returns all of the group members for each group. But I want to identify if each group member has at least one 'active' device.  To do this I am using Row_Number and partitioning on groupID and memberID and ordering by the 'Active' column which is a BIT type.
The results of this below query are correct.  But I am only using a subset of data.  I read that because a bit column is not a number, you should not order by it.  It can produce unpredictable results.

How can I cast the BIT column to an INT and use it in the ROW_NUMBER function?

This is the query:

```
WITH OrderedGroupMembers AS
(
SELECT g.GroupID AS GroupID, gm.RecipientID AS MemberID, r.RecipientName AS MemberName, d.Active AS ActiveDevice,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY g.GroupID, gm.RecipientID ORDER BY d.Active DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM PagingToolGroups g JOIN PagingToolGroupMembers gm ON g.GroupID = gm.GroupID
        JOIN PagingToolRecipients r ON r.RecipientID = gm.RecipientID
        JOIN PagingToolDevices d ON d.RecipientID = gm.RecipientID
WHERE g.GroupCreatorID = 'ge39se35'
)
SELECT GroupID, MemberID, MemberName, ActiveDevice
FROM OrderedGroupMembers
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
This is my new query but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it...

```
WITH OrderedGroupMembers AS
(
SELECT GroupID, MemberID, MemberName, ActiveDevice, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID, MemberID ORDER BY ActiveDevice DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM (
        SELECT g.GroupID AS GroupID, gm.RecipientID AS MemberID, r.RecipientName AS MemberName, CAST(d.Active AS INT) ActiveDevice  
        FROM PagingToolGroups g JOIN PagingToolGroupMembers gm ON g.GroupID = gm.GroupID
                JOIN PagingToolRecipients r ON r.RecipientID = gm.RecipientID
                JOIN PagingToolDevices d ON d.RecipientID = gm.RecipientID
        WHERE g.GroupCreatorID = 'ge35s39'
    ) AS ActiveAsNum
)
SELECT GroupID, MemberID, MemberName, ActiveDevice
FROM OrderedGroupMembers
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Cast(d.active as int)?

Comment: If you do this in the SELECT statement, the ROW_NUMBER function will not use the cast value but the bit type...won't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with bit type. You can order by column with bit type as any other type. One restriction with bits is you can not aggregate on one but you can cast it to any numeric type in that case. But this is not that case so you just order by Active column. It is legal and there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Thanks!  I am just a little paranoid.